# Projecting onto span of $(\gamma,\gamma',...,\gamma^{(k)})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, furthermore, assume $\gamma(t),\gamma'(t),...,\gamma^{(n-1)}(t)$ are linearly independent for all $t$. If $i=0,...,n-1$, let $\pi_i$ be the orthogonal projection on to the span of $\gamma,\gamma',...,\gamma^{(i)}$. Prove that for every $i$ dimension subspace $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is impossible that $\dim (\pi_i A)<i$ for all $t$.

Here $\gamma^{k}$ means the $k$th derivative of $\gamma$.

This is easy to show if $i=0$,but how to show it in general?